# iText: Compare font after processing string using FontSelector

Tags: java, fonts, itext, arabic, hebrew

**tl;dr**:
In iText, is there a way to access the font's name, or figure out the language of a font that has been applied to a Phrase from a FontSelector?

---

This question is in relation to an issue we've been having for the [printwikipedia project](http://printwikipedia.com) --- [github](https://github.com/mandiberg/printwikipedia/) -- [issue](https://github.com/mandiberg/printwikipedia/issues/12) .

I have a body of text that I do not have control over coming in to a FontSelector to be processed. Some of that text is in Arabic and some is in Hebrew and I am trying to figure out the best way of detecting the type of font in order to have it print correctly as seen here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-persian-content-pdf
using

```
pdfCell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

After running the strings through the FontSelector to become Phrases and then placing them within the cell formatted with the code above all the text ends up on the right.

Formatting of this text is very important so I cannot have all of my text aligned to the right but only when it is meant to be read as right to left. So what I believe should be the best course of action is to detect the font that has been applied to the Phrase and then alter the cell if necessary.

```
public FontSelector fs = new FontSelector();
// add a whole lot of fonts to fs
// incoming line of some sort of text
Phrase ph = fs.process(line);
System.out.println(ph.getFont().toString());
```

The above code will output some extremely varied results. Pretty much a new id for every font created for each piece of text. I can't figure out a way to compare a font that exists in the fontselector object with a font that has been applied to the incoming text.

Is this the best method to figure out what fonts are in a phrase?

How can I access the font's name, or figure out the language of a font that has been applied to a Phrase from a FontSelector?

Comment: Is this about the Print Wikipedia art project? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_Wikipedia

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, yes indeed.

Comment: I see you already found an answer to your question. But I have a question for you. Is there any reason why you are not using a recent version of iText (current is 5.5.8)? I saw in the repository that you are using 2.1.7. Most of the time when people use the old version it's because they want to make money using iText in commercial software, but don't want to pay a license. But Printwikipedia doesn't seem to be a commercial product, at least not the software part of it, so the AGPL version of iText could maybe be an option for you.

Comment: Printwikipedia is certainly not a commercial product. Updating was put on the backburner until recently because of many time constraints that we were under for the project. We are not under so many constraints now so we definitely plan to update soon. Thank you for your comment and iText   :)

Comment: I want to say this personally, not as an employee of iText: I can really appreciate the concept of Printwikipedia. I had already heard about it before I started working at iText. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

I went through the itext [documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/classes) a bit more carefully and discovered my answer.

[Phrases](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.Phrase) are made up of [Chunks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.Chunk) which contain the fonts. If one simple does a .getChunks() command on the output phrase and then iterators over the chunks they can then compare the fonts by doings a .getFont() on the chunks in the arraylist and proceeding to apply whatever styles you wish from there.